# react-native start freeze system .100% cpu usage and HIP increasing

Tags: react-native

When i run react-native start system getting freeze in a minute . hip size going gradually high and ram getting 100%

console is just showing

**Loading dependency graph...**

i try many uninstall and reinstall not working

I'm using Ubuntu and latest react native 
all project same

my step

```
react-native init AwesomeProjec
cd AwesomeProjec
npm start
```

Comment: Did you reinstall metro already?

Comment: I can confirm this. Running Ubuntu 18, react native v0.60. After starting `node` (v12.6.0) takes up 100% cpu until the system freezes. The dependency graph gets loaded (Done) in my case and my app is the standard thing you get after `react-native init`.

Comment: The issue is not consistently reproducible. Right now, without reinstalling, things work out fine.

Comment: i reinstalled many time. node ,react native  . finally i bypass issue by downgrading to 0.59

Comment: Wow, that was frustrating. I downgraded too, and don't have any issues now (downgraded Node from 12 to 10 as well)